# Unable to deploy Spring Boot application in Wildfly 8 AS

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly

I am new to Spring Boot and am facing problem in deploying Spring Boot application to Wildfly 8 server. I followed some links found in internet to deploy Spring Boot application as war file but did not work.

My pom.xml file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My starter class is as below:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have exposed a Rest method and the Rest Controller looks as below:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public class HelloController {
        @RequestMapping("/sayHello")
        public String sayHello( ) {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
```

My project runs in embedded tomcat but not in Wildfly server. Please help.

Comment: Pls show console erro

Comment: When I am deploying in a server and hitting http://<<serverName>>:<<port>>/hello/sayHello, the URL is not getting hit. No errors but it is unaccessible

Comment: you used both server used Tomcat and  Wildfly 8 server, first you remove the tomcat dependencies in pom.xml file then work fine. i hope @Anirban

Comment: In my pom.xml I have already excluded tomcat dependency with artifact id spring-boot-starter-tomcat

Comment: What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any exception while deploying the application, try to access the application by hitting the following URL and check if it works:
http://<>:<>/**name_of_your_war**/hello/sayHello